# How defining a module signature whose module implementation is parameterized by a functor

Tags: module, functional-programming, ocaml, functor

Let's say I have a module `M` parameterized by a module `F`:

```
module M (F : sig type id type data end) =
struct
 type idtype = F.id
 type datatype = F.data
 type component = { id : idtype; data : datatype }
 let create id data = { id; data }
 let get_comp_data comp = comp.data
 let get_comp_id comp = comp.id
end
```

so I use it like this :

```
module F1 = struct type id = int type data = float end
module MF1 = M(F1)

let comp = MF1.create 2 5.0
let id = MF1.get_comp_id comp
```

Now, if I want `M` to match signature `S` :

```
module type S = 
sig
  type idtype
  type datatype 
  type component
  val create : idtype -> datatype -> component
  val get_comp_data : component -> datatype
  val get_comp_id : component -> idtype
end

module F1 = struct type id = int type data = float end
module MF1 = (M(F1) : S)

let comp = MF1.create 2 5.0
let id = MF1.get_comp_id comp
```

what bothers me here is, in order to define `get_comp_data` and `get_comp_id`, I need to 
specify `idtype` and `datatype` in module `S`; now just imagine I have other records types in `M` with their own types, I'll have a dozen types to specify in `S`? Is there a simpler way to avoid that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The natural way to do this is to seal the module at the definition site, not the use site. Then you just need to express the type sharing once:

```
module M (F : sig type id type data end) :
  S with type idtype = F.id and datatype = F.data
  = struct ... end
```

If your functor parameter is more complex then you can also just share an entire module instead of individual types. For example:

```
module type TYPES = sig type id type data (* ...and more... *) end

module type S = 
sig
  module Types : TYPES
  type component
  val create : Types.id -> Types.data -> component
  val get_comp_data : component -> Types.data
  val get_comp_id : component -> Types.id
end

module M (F : TYPES) : S with module Types = F
  = struct ... end
```

Or you can even parameterise the signature itself, by nesting it into another functor:

```
module type TYPES = sig type id type data (* ...and more... *) end

module S (F : TYPES) =
struct
  module type S =
  sig
    type component
    val create : F.id -> F.data -> component
    val get_comp_data : component -> F.data
    val get_comp_id : component -> F.id
  end
end

module M (F : TYPES) : S(F).S
  = struct ... end
```

Comment: didn't know you can place a module in another module with the same name; nasty